# Using a php variable in a link(CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to be able to create a link using a variable (which changes depending on what is outputted from the a database). So `if $name = dave`, I would like to be able to say:

```
www.example.com/$name
```

which would be the same as:

```
www.example.com/dave
```

I have tried the following

```
foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $name = $row['user_username'];
    echo anchor('User/view/$name', '$name'); 
}
```

but get the following error:

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable shouldn't be in quotes:

```
echo anchor('User/view/'.$name, $name);
```

should work.

Comment: But can be in double quote ``anchor("User/view/$name", $name);``

Answer (score 2):

If you do

```
www.example.com/dave
```

It will go to a PHP page called dave, I dont think that is what you want.

To use variables in links you have to do something like this

```
www.example.com?name=dave
```

Also if you do

```
echo anchor('User/view/$name', '$name');
```

It will post '$name' and not what is in the var. Delete the single quotes: `'...'`